# require ext-xml * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xml extension

Tags: php, xml

I'm learning laravel. But after running the command `composer update` it is showing me this error.

I've already done this -> `apt-get install php7.4-xml` and `apt-get install php-xml`

I just want to know **which line should I add** to the file php.ini to enable the PHP's xml extension. Thanks in Advance.

```
php--version 

PHP 7.4.22 (cli) (built: Jul 30 2021 13:08:17) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.4.22, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Result of `composer udpate`

```
    aman@aman-HP-Notebook:~/AMAN/learnLaravel$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.



 Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit[9.3.3, ..., 9.5.x-dev] require ext-xml * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xml extension.
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^9.3.3 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[9.3.3, ..., 9.5.x-dev].To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
    You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

result of `sudo apt search php-xml`

```
i   php-xml                                                  - DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP [default]       
v   php-xml:i386                                             -                                                                   
p   php-xml-htmlsax3                                         - SAX parser for HTML and other badly formed XML documents          
p   php-xml-rpc2                                             - PHP XML-RPC client/server library                                 
p   php-xml-svg                                              - XML_SVG API                                                       
v   php-xml-util                                             -                                                                   
v   php-xmlreader                                            -                                                                   
v   php-xmlreader:i386                                       -                                                                   
p   php-xmlrpc                                               - XML-RPC servers and clients functions for PHP                     
v   php-xmlrpc:i386                                          -                                                                   
p   php-xmlrpc-all-dev                                       - XML-RPC servers and clients functions for PHP                     
v   php-xmlwriter                                            -                                                                   
v   php-xmlwriter:i386                                       -
```

output of `php -m`

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Comment: If you are on ubuntu apt-get install should be enough.

Comment: What's your default php version? Type `php --version` to check it.

Comment: @toyi , I've mentioned php --version in questions's description. (I've just added)

Comment: Have you done a restart of `nginx/apache` and `php-fpm` since doing the `apt install`?

Comment: @Peppermintology No need to restart anything since the php cli is used by composer, not php-fpm. Technically, it should works. Can you do a composer update and copy/paste the complete output in your question please?

Comment: okay sure @toyi

Comment: Also I forgot, can you check php-xml is enabled by doing `php -m | grep xml`? Thank you. It should return some lines containing `xml`. If not, then php-xml is not installed properly.

Comment: @toyi the result of composer result is in the description. Please check it

Comment: @toyi  result of `php-m | grep xml` is `libxml`

Comment: That's probably the problem, for instance on my system, I have `libxml`, `xml`, `xmlreader` and `xmlwriter`

Comment: @toyi so how can I install these remaining two's `xml` and `xmlreader`

Comment: I need more space I'll write an answer, feel free to comment under it and I'll update with what we find it until it works

Comment: okay sure @toyi. Thanks for you time. Please go ahead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to answer in a professional way. But I've added only these following three lines in `php.ini` file by guessing.

```
extension=xmlwriter.so
extension=xml.so
extension=xmlreader.so
```

and yes, it is working now.

Note : In my case, `php.ini` file is located inside `etc/php/7.4/cli`.
Thanks Toyi for your help and time.

Comment: I deleted my answer since yours is obviously the right one. Glad it works, have a nice day  ! :)

Comment: On Debian, there's a 'phpenmod' command which should have done this for you - I think it's something like : 

phpenmod -v $VERSION -s $SAPI xml  - e.g. phpenmod -v 7.4 -s cli xml .... you can also use "ALL" for version and sapi if you just want it everywhere

Answer (score 17):

This PHP extension is usually enabled by default but if you're on Ubuntu there's a chance it isn't.

To resolve this you just need to install the php-xml extension via apt-get.

Run the following: `apt-get install php-xml`

If you get the following error(s): `404  Not Found` on running that command then you likely just need to update via `apt-get update` and then run the php-xml command again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case running `apt-get install php-xml` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74854980) did not work.

I needed to adapt the answer to use my current php version (8.1):

```
apt install php8.1-xml
```

Make sure to match your php version.

Comment: Did you mean the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68873746/16343464)? or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74854980)? I edited the answer, please double check that my modification keeps the intended meaning.