# PROBLEM while create a new project in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, vendor

I am learning to create projects with laravel, I am using PHP 8. When creating a new project through "laravel new project".I got this error and vendor folder is missiing in that project.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel new-project - laravel/framework[v8.65.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
    - league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.65 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.65.0, ..., 8.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\Program Files\php-8.0.12\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: Are the extensions available in your ext folder? Just because It's enabled in your php.ini file doesn't mean that you have that extension.

Comment: "_require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system_" An extension is missing. Did you "_verify that they are enabled in your .ini files_"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer: The requested PHP extension ext-intl \* is missing from your system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332031/composer-the-requested-php-extension-ext-intl-is-missing-from-your-system)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68873115/require-ext-xml-it-is-missing-from-your-system-install-or-enable-phps-xml

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775897/how-do-i-install-the-ext-curl-extension-with-php-7

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408604/php7-install-ext-dom-issue

Answer (score 3):

removing ; before extension = fileinfo from php.ini inside PHP folder in this path "C:\Program Files\php-8.0.12/" but I didn't remove it from "C:\Program Files\php-8.0.12/php.ini".

Comment: If you help this answer so please up this answer becouse another user can use for that.

Answer (score 0):

On this file `C:\Program Files\php-8.0.12\php.ini` add this line:

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

This should enable the missing extension on the system.