# composer create-project fails

Tags: php, composer-php

I just installed PHP and trying to create a skeleton project.

I installed PHP 7.1, composer and ran the command `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton test_symp` but it failed with versions number incorrect.

So I thought this is old versions and those tools don't manage correctly dependencies, so let's install latest version.

I installed PHP 8.1, and retried but it still fails.

Here are the logs :

```
$ composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton test_symp
Creating a "symfony/website-skeleton" project at "./test_symp"
Installing symfony/website-skeleton (v6.1.99)
  - Installing symfony/website-skeleton (v6.1.99): Extracting archive
Created project in /home/simon/test_symp
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking symfony/flex (v2.2.5)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/flex (v2.2.5): Extracting archive
Generating optimized autoload files
1 package you are using is looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Loading composer repositories with package information
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "6.1.*"
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/framework-bundle 6.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v6.1.0, ..., v6.1.11].
    - symfony/framework-bundle[v6.1.0, ..., v6.1.11] require ext-xml * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xml extension.
  Problem 2
    - symfony/webapp-pack[v1.0.0, ..., v1.2.0] require symfony/security-bundle * -> satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v6.1.0, ..., v6.1.12].
    - symfony/security-bundle[v6.1.0, ..., v6.1.12] require ext-xml * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xml extension.
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/webapp-pack * -> satisfiable by symfony/webapp-pack[v1.0.0, ..., v1.2.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
```

How can I get a correct install ?

Comment: **This was the clue** `Install or enable PHP's xml extension.` It look like you are a linux user, so you have to install some of the PHP extensions as well as PHP itself. something like `sudo apt-get install -y php-xml`

Comment: It was already done : simon@node:~/test_symp$ sudo apt-get install -y php-xml
[sudo] Mot de passe de simon : 
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait      
php-xml est déjà la version la plus récente (2:8.2+93+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+2).
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 105 non mis à jour.

Comment: Then did you activate it in the `php.ini` by removing the `;` comment from the `extension` line

Comment: Oh and as you are using the CLI for this, make sure you are amending the correct `php.ini` To check, do `>php --ini` from the terminal and look at `Loaded Configuration File:` That will tell you the path to the ini file that is actually beig used

Comment: I see no ext-xml in the extension= list. What is it ? I tried to add extension=ext-xml but it doesn't work

Comment: `extension=xml.so`

Comment: or I think there is a `phpenmod` command like `phpenmod -v 7.4 -s cli xml `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [require ext-xml \* -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xml extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68873115/require-ext-xml-it-is-missing-from-your-system-install-or-enable-phps-xml)

Comment: ...did you **read** the error message? Also, why did you install PHP 7.1 to resolve this problem? That version is horribly outdated and shouldn't be used for any new project nowadays

Answer (score 0):

I had to install those :

```
sudo apt install php8.1-curl php8.1-xml
```

(adding the extensions curl and xml in the php.ini was failing as the curl was not the one expected (???))